# PYTHON: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'hand'

Tags: python, python-2.7, int, attributeerror

So I have an exercise on python - building a BlackJack game.
I have started with defining how every phrase of the game would go.
Now when I run this code below, In case the input is '0' - which means you don't want cards anymore, it runs perfectly. But when the input is '1' - which means you want to pick card, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Maymon/PycharmProjects/untitled4/BlackJack.py", line 1, in <module>
    class blackjack(object):
  File "C:/Users/Maymon/PycharmProjects/untitled4/BlackJack.py", line 34, in blackjack
    player(1)
  File "C:/Users/Maymon/PycharmProjects/untitled4/BlackJack.py", line 25, in player
    PickCard(1)
  File "C:/Users/Maymon/PycharmProjects/untitled4/BlackJack.py", line 18, in PickCard
    self.hand+= random.randrange(1, 13)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'hand'
```

The code:

```
class blackjack(object):

    #this func defines how player should react
    def player(self):

        #this func defines what case of technical loosing
        def loser():
            print("You have reached", hand , ". Which is beyond 21. Therefor, you have lost the game. Better luck next time!")


        #this func is responsible for picking card issue.
        def PickCard(self):
            import random
            x=1
            while x == 1:
                pick = int(raw_input("Enter 1 if you want another card, else Enter 0"))
                if pick == 1:
                    self.hand = self.hand + random.randrange(1, 13)
                else:
                    x=0
        import random
        print "Now your first card will automatically be given to you:"
        hand=random.randrange(1,13)
        print "hand: ", hand
        PickCard(1)
        print hand
        if hand>21:
            loser()
        elif hand==21:
            pass
        else:
            pass

    player(1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `self` is an integer in that function, because you called `PickCard(1)`. I'm not sure why you used the name `self` there as it is not a method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the function call as `player(1)` where the `player` function expects the argument as of `self` type .i.e. instance of the class `blackjack`. Hence, while doing `self.hand = self.hand + random.randrange(1, 13)` it is throwing the above mentioned error.

---

*I think* you do not want to make a call to `player()` function from within the class, Is it? Move that part to outside the class. Firstly create the object of class `blackjack` (Note: In Python, class names should be defined as CamelCase variables like: BlackJack). For example:

```
blackjack_obj = blackjack()
```

Then call the `player()` function as:

```
blackjack_obj.player()
```

Comment: First of all thank you. Now I cant call player() from outside the class because I defined it inside it. I haven't understood what you meant about     'code'(blackjack_obj)'code' , and about the "self"

Comment: `blackjack` is class. By `blackjack_obj = blackjack()` I am creating object of `blackjack` as `blackjack_obj`. Now you may call the functions defined within in the class using the object of class.

Comment: Please also refer [Python Class Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects) to get more clarity regarding the class and its objects.

Comment: Thank you, I'm afraid the Python virsion which is in the link "Python Class Objects" does not fit with what I should learn. I am using Python 2.7, not 3.4.

Comment: This behaviour is same in both Python 2.7 and Python 3 :)

Comment: so I found the problem: self.<variable> - the variable can't be an int. So now I have another problem. I deleted the "self." and now I get this issue: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
 .......
    hand = hand + random.randrange(1, 13)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hand' referenced before assignment'

Comment: `self.hand` part was fine in your code. After defining tha class, execute the statements I mentioned at the last of my answer for calling the function i.e. call the function as `<class _obj>.player()`

Comment: Thank you very much, I have solved my problem. Now my only problem is how to run the code for multiple players. I am now trying 'p1=player()' after I added 'return hand' by the end of the func 'player()', but it seems like I can't do that

Comment: Never mind. All solved. Thank you very much for your help.